# Creating new column doesn't display correct number of item

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list (collection), a total of 7 item which I'm looping through to create a gridview inside a listview. I also have a check that for example if the row count is 5, this will create a new column by adding 1 to it. The problem is when the row count is equal to 5 and is true, the first column will have the 7 items regardless and when the second column is created, it doesn't show the remaining 2 items. Instead it shows all 7 items again.

Can anyone help, what am I doing wrong?

```
foreach (var item in lstOfSoda)
{
    GridLength rowheight1 = new GridLength();
    RowDefinition rowDef1 = new RowDefinition { Height = rowheight1 };
    grdSoda.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef1);

    GridLength rowheight2 = new GridLength();
    RowDefinition rowDef2 = new RowDefinition { Height = rowheight2 };
    grdSoda.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef2);

    GridLength columnwidth1 = new GridLength(231);
    ColumnDefinition colDef1 = new ColumnDefinition { Width = columnwidth1 };
    grdSoda.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef1);

    GridLength columnwidth2 = new GridLength(5);
    ColumnDefinition colDef2 = new ColumnDefinition { Width = columnwidth2 };
    grdSoda.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef2);

    ListView lvSoda = new ListView();
    lvSoda.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, row + 1);
    lvSoda.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, column);
    grdSoda.Children.Add(lvSoda);

    GridView gridView = new GridView();

    GridViewColumn gvcSodaName = new GridViewColumn();
    gvcSodaName.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("SodaName");
    gridView.Columns.Add(gvcSodaName);

    GridViewColumn gvcSodaFlavor = new GridViewColumn();
    gvcSodaFlavor.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("SodaFlavor");
    gridView.Columns.Add(gvcSodaFlavor);

    lvSoda.ItemsSource = lstOfSoda;
    lvSoda.View = gridView;
    rowCount++;

    if (rowCount == 5)
    {
        column = column + 2;
        rowCount = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define "show all items again".

Comment: @Patrick -- It'll display all 7 items.

Comment: But you are binding them all to lstOfSoda;

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to do this in XAML?

Comment: @Patrick -- I can do this in xaml but if I do it in xalm, how would I make it so every 5 it creates a new column and display the remaining?

Comment: @Blam -- can you help with my code to get the result I'm looking for?

Comment: I would go about this differently and just got done being chastised down voted for offering a solution that was not a direct answer to the question as stated.